# ruamel.yaml ComposerError when using alias/ as name

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I am trying to parse the following document

```yaml
hello:
  there: &there_value 1
foo:
  *there_value: 3
```

This gets correctly parsed with the safe loader:

```py
>>> from ruamel.yaml import YAML

>>> document = """
... hello:
...   there: &there_value 1
... foo:
...   *there_value: 3
"""

>>> yaml=YAML(typ="safe")
>>> yaml.load(document)
{'hello': {'there': 1}, 'foo': {1: 3}}
```

The round-trip (standard) loader throws an error:

```py
>>> yaml=YAML()
>>> yaml.load(document)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\main.py", line 434, in load
    return constructor.get_single_data()
  File "...\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\constructor.py", line 119, in get_single_data
    node = self.composer.get_single_node()
  File "...\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\composer.py", line 76, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "...\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\composer.py", line 99, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "...\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\composer.py", line 143, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "...\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\composer.py", line 223, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "...\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\composer.py", line 117, in compose_node
    raise ComposerError(
ruamel.yaml.composer.ComposerError: found undefined alias 'there_value:'
  in "<unicode string>", line 6, column 3:
      *there_value: 3
      ^ (line: 6)
```

I am using Python `3.8.10`, ruamel.yaml version `0.17.21`.

Comment: That is a strange error in round-trip mode, and I think that is a bug. What is for sure a bug is how the safeloader loads that, contrary to your claim that it is correct ( It should load as `{'hello': {'there': 1}, 'foo': 3}` as the second anchor is `there_value:` since `:` is a valid anchor character (https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.1/#ns-anchor-char)

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake copying and pasting the code, there is no second anchor. I updated the code in the question.

Comment: Then there is no bug in `ruamel.yaml`, but there is in the C extension. As I indicated the `:` is a valid character in an anchor name, so you need to put a space between the alias and the colon `*therevalue : 3` (or alternatively define the anchor `therevalue:` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anthon suggested in their comment, `:` is a valid character for an anchor,
so `*there_value:` is looking for `there_value:` which is not defined, only `there_value` is.

The solution is to add a space after the anchor, `*there_value :`.

```yaml
hello:
  there: &there_value 1
foo:
  *there_value : 3
```

This loads correctly both with round-trip and with safe.